# Which book is an introduction to non-deprecated OpenGL shader programming?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I need to port a legacy app which uses deprecated OpenGL code (`glRotate` etc.) into shaders. However, OpenGL has been changing rapidly lately and I'd like to avoid learning an approach that is already marked as deprecated. So, is there a modern day OpenGL shaders book, perhaps similar in style to the old "The Cg tutorial" book?

Answer (score 6):

[Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) is rather new and already covers a lot of topics.

Comment: If anybody interested in running the tutorials on OS X, I have a port to Xcode+GLFW3 here: https://github.com/rsanchezsaez/gltut-glfw

Answer (score -1):

[The OpenGL SuperBible Fifth Edition](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/) covers OpenGL 3.3